# Telerik MVC Grid - Multiple data rows result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using telerik grid for display data from sql db... When I displaying more than 3500 rows, it returns: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Everywhere on internet and [Telerik Troubleshooting manual](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-troubleshooting.html#MaximumJsonLength) also too, wrote that reason is edit web.config. It doesn't help me... I tryed return data like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = 536870912, RecursionLimit = 100 };
return new ContentResult()
{
    Content = serializer.Serialize(data),
    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
```

When I return data as ContentResult, filtering and sorting stops working.

I was trying this solution too: http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/large-json-result-for-teleriks-mvc-grid/ and it isn't helps me...

Here is code from my Controller:

```
[GridAction, POST("GridData")]
public ActionResult _Index()
{
    var data = GetExclusionsDataCollection();
 
    return View(new GridModel { Data = data });
}
```

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i contacted Telerik support and now I can share reason of my issue...

There is [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/using-custom-jsonresult-with-ajax-bound-grid.aspx) to Telerik Code library. Important part is adding line into global.asax.cs. This part of their solution isn't in most of other solutions that i have seen...

```
DI.Current.Register<IGridActionResultFactory>(() => new MyCustomGridActionResultFactory());
```

This line causes ovveride default Telerik functionality and active your custom Json result...

-David

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the maxRequestLength in web.config

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="VALUE" />
</system.web>
```

where Value will be set to int.maxvalue or int64.maxvalue